# converting to date type from 2017 Apr to 2017-04-01 in r

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the following to a data object in R, such that its the first of the month "2017-04-01", "2015,-07-01", "2014-09-01" etc.

I have tried splitting the column and using:

```
mutate(numeric_month = match(month, month.abb))
```

data

```
c("2017 Apr", "2015 Jul", "2014 Sep", "2014 Sep", "2016 Jun", "2015 Mar", "2016 Jul", "2017 Jan", "2014 Dec")
```

Comment: This approach works and I generally prefer it to others, but just in case it is interesting to you, `zoo` has a `yearmon()` class which could be helpful if you are doing time series work on a date defined by only year and month.

Comment: `as.Date(paste(vec, "01"), format = "%Y %b %d")`

Comment: `as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(d, "%Y %b"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Up front*: this is not intended as a replacement for @wusel's answer, from which I borrowed `truncated=1`; more-so this is meant to augment and inform the decision. While `lubridate` and associated packages are often a quick answer, it may also be good (even preferred at times) to understand base R methods as well.

---

There are several packages that will do very good "guessing" about formats, including `lubridate` and `anytime`. These often handle (well-enough) variable formats, common in human-generated data.

Sometimes, their functions are faster, but not always. For instance, the base R approach below is 100x faster with your sample vec of 9 elements. `lubridate::ymd` does not reach parity until around 9000 elements, at which time it is as fast as the base R solution.

If you're concerned about external library dependencies, then a base R solution might be good enough:

```r
vec <- c("2017 Apr", "2015 Jul", "2014 Sep", "2014 Sep", "2016 Jun", "2015 Mar", "2016 Jul", "2017 Jan", "2014 Dec")
as.Date(paste(vec, "01"), format = "%Y %b %d") 
# [1] "2017-04-01" "2015-07-01" "2014-09-01" "2014-09-01" "2016-06-01"
# [6] "2015-03-01" "2016-07-01" "2017-01-01" "2014-12-01"
```

Performance can be an issue, and the external libraries do not always start faster than base R. For instance, see the benchmarks below. (I've omitted the call to `microbenchmark` for all but the first, for brevity.)

```r
ovec <- vec # for easy replication

vec <- ovec # unmodified, length 9
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base=as.Date(paste(vec, "01"), format = "%Y %b %d"),
  lub=lubridate::ymd(vec, truncated=1),
  any=anytime::anydate(vec)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#  base   24.8   32.75   44.030   40.65   48.45   96.6   100
#   lub 1930.2 2220.15 2493.421 2470.70 2600.55 3988.9   100
#   any  843.4 1028.55 1100.802 1064.70 1117.35 1786.7   100

vec <- rep(ovec, 100) # length 900
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq     max neval
#  base  1.0186  1.03205  1.077106  1.05280  1.0821  1.7377   100
#   lub  3.7256  3.85880  4.078732  3.99555  4.1191  7.6760   100
#   any 80.2832 81.01845 81.866035 81.38680 82.0539 94.5261   100

vec <- rep(ovec, 1000) # length 9000
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  base  10.0675  10.21355  10.54913  10.34485  10.61695   13.6982   100
#   lub   9.9044  10.17945  10.57318  10.29240  10.57785   13.3987   100
#   any 809.8678 820.55190 842.60012 825.04555 845.02495 1132.2419   100
```

(I'm likely doing something wrong with `anytime`, I had expected it to soar a bit faster given the inputs. I'll take suggestions to improve this comparison if I'm missing something.)

As you can see, the `lubridate` solution runs in about the same time when the data is length 9000. For giggles, at 10x that, the `lubridate::ymd` solution does much better (omitting `anytime`):

```r
vec <- rep(ovec, 10000)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr     min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
#  base 99.1428 101.35455 111.49082 106.3730 119.97595 183.0905   100
#   lub 36.0184  37.09255  42.45397  40.2352  46.85875  74.5182   100
```

Comment: Another advantage of your approach is that you can directly set the "day" value as desired. While most of the times the 1st of each month is needed, if not, your code is more flexible here.

Answer (score 3):

That is easily achieved with `lubridate` and the `truncated`-argument.

```
library(magrittr)
c("2017 Apr", "2015 Jul", "2014 Sep", "2014 Sep", "2016 Jun", "2015 Mar", "2016 Jul", "2017 Jan", "2014 Dec") %>% 
  lubridate::ymd(truncated = 1)
```

---

*Edit:*
A note on the `truncated` argument:

`lubridate` has a lot of functions with which you can easily define just the order in which your date/datetime information is stored. However, it does not cover all possible cases. For example, there is no `ym()` function for your specific case but truncated basically says how many of your date-parts can be missing.

It can also be helpful in case you have inconsistent data where sometimes less information is given. Check the difference here whether you set `truncated` to `1` or `2`:

```
c("2017 Apr", "2015 Jul", "2014 ", "2014 Sep", "2016 Jun", "2015 Mar", "2016 Jul", "2017 Jan", "2014 Dec") %>% 
  lubridate::ymd(truncated = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! whats the significance of `truncated = 1`?

Comment: Its doc says: *"If the 'truncated' parameter is non-zero, the 'ymd' functions also check for truncated formats. For example 'ymd()' with 'truncated = 2' will also parse incomplete dates like '2012-06' and '2012'."*